# Return the gradient and y intercept (m, b) to create two lines to best fit the data

Tags: dataset, linear-regression, graphs

I have been working on this task for a few hours now and have been unsuccessful with getting the target result. I have tried using multiple methods of trying to split the dataset using different clustering methods and logistical regression with no luck. I thought noncontinuous piecewise linear regression may work however found no good resources on how to implement it.

The taks is given a 2D NumPy array of x, y data points determine the gradient and y-intercept for exactly two lines that best fit the data. Here is an example photo where the two blue lines show what a "solved" solution looks like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have a formulation for [mixture models in pytorch here](https://github.com/apwheele/Blog_Code/blob/master/Using%20Pytorch%20for%20group%20based%20trajectory%20models.ipynb). Here is a [linear programming formulation](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/03/a-difficult-multiline-regression-data.html).

Comment: I would start with 2 models of lines ($(m_1,b_1), (m_2,b_2)$) and succesively try to fit (starting with 4 random points) each point in both of them. The next point to fit would be tried on both of them, this which gives the smallest error is classified as point of line 1 or 2 (and line coefficients are re-calculated).  And so on, untill all points are covered

Comment: Or even better start with the lines being orthogonal to each other. ie each line represents initially X or Y axis. In this way the lines are not colinear so they represent different classes of points

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to take a hierarchical approach:

1. Separate the values into two clusters. Since connectiveness within a cluster is important, use an algorithm like spectral clustering.
2. Fit a separate regression line to each respective cluster.